# select * columns but group by two specific columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

In the tab above you can see several records in some cases the Material column of the record n ​​is equal to the record n ​​+ 1 and in the Material column Desc the record n ​​is equal to the record n ​​+ 1.

But it does not make the columns List `Price USD` and `RVS-ZSEG` what happens is that I need to make a group by or combine the pairs in some registers but that they become complementary.

For example that in register
1 and 2 would be converted by combining the values ​​of `List Price USD` and `RVS ZSEG` should be shown as image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Material, MaterialDesc
    ,MAX([D-Chain-Spec(Status)])[D-Chain-Spec(Status)]
    ,MAX([List Price USD])[List Price USD]
    ,MAX([RVS - ZSEG])[RVS - ZSEG]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Material, MaterialDesc
```

Comment: Hello sorry for answered this until now but I have been very bussy as this question save my life lol not literally. any ways it worked perfectly fine.!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you just need a sum on List Price USD and RVS-ZSEG right?

```
SELECT Material, MaterialDesc,[D-Chain-Spec(Status)]
    ,SUM([List Price USD]) as [List Price USD]
    ,SUM([RVS - ZSEG]) as [RVS - ZSEG]
FROM Table
GROUP BY Material, MaterialDesc,[D-Chain-Spec(Status)]
```